# Dell T5500 - System board regulator failure

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

So, could someone tell me what "system board regulator failure" accually means?
Is the Motherboard broken? And what could cause the problem?

Comment: Not certain, but sounds like a piece of hardware on the motherboard is failing.  Probably power related, probably not user-repairable.  A Dell technician might be able to tell specifically.  If the machine were still under warranty, I'd have Dell replace it, but the T5500s were introduced in 2009.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, do you think it would help to change the motherboard?

Comment: @Tyler - Will replacing the motherboard fix a problem caused by a bad motherboard, Yes, if the problem is caused by your motherboard that is the fix action to your problem.  We cannot confirm if your problem is caused by a bad motherboard though.